# iOS Fixed Elements Hidden on Input Focus

Tags: html, ios, css

This wasn't happening previously for me, but I updated to iOS 9.3 two weeks ago and now hidden elements on my web page are hidden when the keyboard is displayed or another input is selected.

Annoyingly a top fixed element is only hidden if the page is scrolled, and the bottom is always hidden. This seems to be a way to 'solve' the issues encountered with fixed elements being left in random positions on the screen when the keyboard is displayed, but now I've got a situation where the elements don't reappear reliably, meaning I lose my main navigation bar for my app.

Is there any way to disable this auto-hiding behaviour? I've created a barebones page that shows the behaviour here: http://128.199.171.247/test.html